# Scene Builder button without text

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to make a button with a graphic only, and Scene Builder won't let me clear the text in the button. It automatically reverts to "Button" for some reason. Is there a way to make this stop?

[image: GIF]

Comment: What version are you using? I just tried in "JavaFX Scene Builder 8.3.0" and I was able to create a button with no text.

Comment: I'm using 8.3.0. How did you get it @WimDeblauwe?

Comment: @theTechnoKid What is drawn on your graphic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine with JavaFX Scene Builder 8.3.0:

[image]

Comment: I am using a custom button control, that is probably the problem. The "Button" text isn't even showing in the properties.

Comment: Maybe you should post a different question, showing the code of your custom control, to find out why the text is not showing in the properties.